# объявление статического члена класса

Tags: c++, ооп

Не могу понять почему в С++ не работает следующий код:

```
class NewClass{
private:
    static std::vector<NewClass*> objects;
    int parametr;
public:
    NewClass::NewClass();
};
NewClass::NewClass(){
    parametr = 0;
    objects.push_back(this);
}
```

Компилятор пишет: *undefined reference to NewClass::objects*
Версия компилятора: *gcc version 5.4.0*

Comment: @Abyx, Просто я думал, что проблема с указателем))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

objects - это статический член класса. К нему надо обращаться через класс

```
NewClass::objects
```

к тому же статические члены класса должны обпределяться вне объявления класса
в вашем случае это должно выглядеть так

```
class NewClass{
private:
    static std::vector<NewClass*> objects;
    int parametr;
public:
    NewClass::NewClass();
};

std::vector<NewClass*> NewClass::objects;

NewClass::NewClass(){
    parametr = 0;
    objects.push_back(this);
}
```

Comment: почему? Простой пример - https://ideone.com/snFsgj.

Comment: для чистоты кода (имхо)

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того, что не `vector<*NewClass>`, а `vector<NewClass*>`.

Далее, тут

```
public:
    NewClass::NewClass();
```

можно обойтись и без `NewClass::`.

А главное - надо *определить* `objects`. Т.е. написать вне класса

```
std::vector<NewClass*> NewClass::objects;
```

(ну, или добавив по необходимости инициализаторы).